# Why is this eigenvector wrong?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

To make this simple I'm going to skip to the part of the problem I'm having trouble with.
I'm trying to find the eigenvector for the eigenvalue $\lambda = 1$, I've done the math and verified this part after putting the matrix in reduced row echelon form we have a $3\times 3$ matrix:
$$\begin{pmatrix}0 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & -3 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$
Therefore,
$v_1 - 3 v_2 = 0$ and $2 v_2 + v_3 = 0$.
This means that $v_1 = 3 v_2$ and $v_3 = -2 v_2$.

This is where I get confused so bear with me.
Because we can define both $v_1$ and $v_3$ with $v_2$, I set $v_2 = t$.
$$[v_1, v_2, v_3] = t[\ ]$$
I think about the problem this way: in order to get $v_1$, what do I multiply "$t$" by? We established earlier that $v_1 = 3 v_2$ or $v_1 = 3 t$, therefore we multiply $t$ by $3$ to get $v_1$, so the first value is $3$.

We repeat. In order to get $v_2$, what do I multiply $t$ by? We established earlier that $v_2 = t$. so the next value is $1$.

In order to get $v_3$, what do we multiply $t$ by? We established earlier that $v_3 = -2 v_2$, therefore $v_3 = -2 t$, so the last value is $-2$.

$$[v_1, v_2, v_3] = t[3, 1, -2]$$

because $3t = v_1$, $t = v_2$, $-2t = v_3$.

I've read my book, read explanations online, and watched video after video (Khan Academy and Krista King Math), yet I still don't understand how to do this.
Apparently the answer is $[-3, -1, 2]$. I'm not sure how the signs flipped, but they did and everywhere I look I can't find an explanation.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  The set $\{t[3,1,-2]\mid t\in\mathbb R\}$ is the same as $\{s[-3,-1,2]\mid s\in\mathbb R\}$; just take $t=-s$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is correct. In fact, $(3,1,-2)$ is still an element of the subspace (*eigenspace*) generated by $(-3,-1,2)$.

If $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ for some eigenvalue $\lambda$, i.e. $Av=\lambda v$, then $-v$ is an eigenvector as well, just as any multiple $\mu v$ (with $\mu\in\mathbb R$, or whatever field you're working on):
$$ Av=\lambda v \ \implies A(\mu v)=\mu (Av)=\mu (\lambda v)= \lambda (\mu v). $$